# Golang: dyld: Symbol not found: _SecCertificateCopyNormalizedSubjectContent

Tags: macos, go, compilation, macos-sierra

I am building a Golang 1.7 (`go version go1.7 darwin/amd64`) application from OSX 10.12 Beta (16A312a) by running this command
`env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 /usr/local/go/bin/go build -ldflags=-s -o dist/program ${GOPATH}src/github.com/owner/repo/program.go`

The program seems to run successfully on OSX 10.7 and above but it breaks in 10.6.8 with the following error:

`dyld: Symbol not found: _SecCertificateCopyNormalizedSubjectContent
  Referenced from: /tmp/program
  Expected in: flat namespace`

I used to compile this same program from OSX 10.11 and it would work on 10.6 and above.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is causing the breakage, but OS X is only supported for versions 10.7 and up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where a perl module built successfully, but subsequently threw that 'dyld:' error. After getting a concussion from pounding my head into a brick wall for a day or two, I discovered that the perl module, which was 32-bit, attempted to dynamically link to a dylib that was 64-bit. Tweaking the perl module to compile as 64-bit resolved this problem.

Upshot: this could be a 32-bit program attempting to 'talk' to a 64-bit dylib.